# How to read XML elements in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a very simple problem, but since I am new to XML, I face some problems.  I have this XML document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<Form_Layout>
  <Location>
    <LocX>100</LocX>
    <LocY>100</LocY>  
  </Location>  
  <Size>  
    <Width>300</Width>  
    <Height>300</Height>  
  </Size>  
</Form_Layout>
```

What I want to do is read the values from the LocX, LoxY, Width, and Height elements into my corresponding variables.

Here is what I have tried:

```
Dim XmlReader = New XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc)  
While XmlReader.Read  
    Select Case XmlReader.Name.ToString()  
        Case "Location"  
            If XmlReader.??  
        Case "Size"  
            If XmlReader.??
    End Select  
End While
```

But, I cannot figure out how to access each child Node.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're able to use Linq to XML, you can use VB's [XML Axis Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384769.aspx):

```
Dim root As XElement = XDocument.Load(fileName).Root

Dim LocX = Integer.Parse(root.<Location>.<LocX>.Value)
Dim LocY = Integer.Parse(root.<Location>.<LocY>.Value)
```

And `root.<Location>.<LocY>.Value = CStr(120)` works too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it with `XmlDocument` and XPath.  I'm sure someone else will be happy to volunteer an example using `XDocument` and LINQ.

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml("...")
Dim locX As Integer = Integer.Parse(doc.SelectSingleNode("/FormLayout/Location/LocX").InnerText)
Dim locY As Integer = Integer.Parse(doc.SelectSingleNode("/FormLayout/Location/LocY").InnerText)
Dim width As Integer = Integer.Parse(doc.SelectSingleNode("/FormLayout/Size/Width").InnerText)
Dim height As Integer = Integer.Parse(doc.SelectSingleNode("/FormLayout/Size/Height").InnerText)
```

Also, you may want to take a look at the `XmlSerializer` class, and see if that is something you are interested in.  That class will read the XML document and use it to populate the property values of a new object.  You just need to create a class that mimics the structure of the XML for it to deserialize into.

Comment: Thank you very much.
if someone can give an example with LINQ I would be very happy

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ-XML,

```
Dim root As XElement = XDocument.Load(fileName).Root

Dim LocX = Integer.Parse(root.Element("Location").Element("LocX").Value)
Dim LocY = Integer.Parse(root.Element("Location").Element("LocY").Value)
```

Comment: An additional question is what if I want to do the opposite:  

    root.Element("Location").Element("LocX").Value=locX 'where locX is my variable  

Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Each XML document may have one declaration node at the top most position. The declaration node gives information about the xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

A root node must be present in the xml document after the declaration node. In your case, the root node is named “Form_Layout”.

```
<Form_Layout>
```

The class objects available in System.Xml namespace may be used to read and manipulate and then save data to and xml file.
You can read the entire contents of an xml file using a filestream object. You can modify nodes and then save it to a new file or overwrite an existing one.
The following code can be used to load an xml file into an XmlDataDocument object.

```
    Dim xmlDoc As System.Xml.XmlDataDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDataDocument
    Dim filepath As String = "C:\Users\mraso\Documents\location.xml"
    Dim loadedIn As Boolean = False, readbln As Boolean = False
    Dim fstream As System.IO.FileStream = New System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)
    If fstream IsNot Nothing Then
        xmlDoc.Load(fstream)
        loadedIn = True
    End If
    fstream.Close()
    fstream.Dispose()
    fstream = Nothing
```

You cand use the ChildNodes property of the XmlDataDocument object to read the declaration node and the root node of the xml document. You may also call ChildNodes property of each node to get its child noted in return.
You can iterate through items in an XmlNodeList object to access individual nodes.
The entire code for working with your xml file is as below.

```
Private Sub TestReadingAndSavingXml()
    Dim xmlDoc As System.Xml.XmlDataDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDataDocument
    Dim filepath As String = "C:\Users\mraso\Documents\location.xml"
    Dim loadedIn As Boolean = False, readbln As Boolean = False
    Dim fstream As System.IO.FileStream = New System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)
    If fstream IsNot Nothing Then
        xmlDoc.Load(fstream)
        loadedIn = True
    End If
    fstream.Close()
    fstream.Dispose()
    fstream = Nothing
    Dim ndList1 As System.Xml.XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.ChildNodes
    If ndList1 IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim cnt As Integer = ndList1.Count
        For Each nd1 As System.Xml.XmlNode In ndList1
            If nd1.Name = "Form_Layout" Then
                Dim nd2 As System.Xml.XmlNode = GetChildNode(nd1, "Location")
                If nd2 IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim nd3 As System.Xml.XmlNode = GetChildNode(nd2, "LocX")
                    If nd3 IsNot Nothing Then
                        Dim LocX_value As Integer = nd3.InnerText
                        Dim s = LocX_value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'Save data to a new xml file
    Dim outputXml As String = "C:\Users\mraso\Documents\location2.xml"
    xmlDoc.Save(outputXml)
End Sub

Function GetChildNode(ByRef node As System.Xml.XmlNode,
                      ByVal nodeName As String) As System.Xml.XmlNode
    If node IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim ndList1 As System.Xml.XmlNodeList = node.ChildNodes
        If ndList1 IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each nd1 As System.Xml.XmlNode In ndList1
                If nd1.Name = nodeName Then
                    Return nd1
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

The above code will read value 100 put inside the node "LocX" in the following xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<Form_Layout>
  <Location>
    <LocX>100</LocX>
    <LocY>100</LocY>  
  </Location>  
  <Size>  
    <Width>300</Width>  
    <Height>300</Height>  
  </Size>  
</Form_Layout>
```