# Inserting text after specific tag

Tags: vb.net, text, insert, tags

I have a text file comprised of different tags. I am able to find out if a specific tag exists within the document using the following...

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim text As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Example.xtp")
    Dim index As Integer = text.IndexOf("<Tools>")
    If index >= 0 Then
        ' String is in file, starting at character "<Tools>" insert text "TEST_HELLO"

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

however I want to also enter extra text after this tag when / if found

I am using VB.net

Comment: I don't know yours text format but maybe you can use xml.

Comment: Its xml based, though I would you segest this futher case im not all to at home with xml?

Comment: Google it and read. Xml will save you time and code. Take a look at my question when I didn't know anything :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581692/how-to-read-xml-elements-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim text As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Example.xtp")
    Dim index As Integer = text.IndexOf("<Tools>")
    Dim countChars as integer
    countChars="<Tools>".Length
    If index >= 0 Then
       ' String is in file, starting at character "<Tools>" insert text "TEST_HELLO"
        text = text.Insert(index + countChars, "TEST_HELLO")
    End If
End Sub
```

*Edit*
If you want to write the final text to a/the file , there are many ways. I just suggest one, but you need to search and read and find what is suitable for you:

```
Dim Writer As System.IO.StreamWriter
Writer = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Textfile.txt") '<-- Where to write to
Writer.Write(text)
Writer.Close()
```

Comment: this line --> countChars=string("<Tools>").Length is giving me trouble do you know why?

Comment: See updated answer. Sorry but I didn't had Visual Studio at that moment.

Comment: yeah I just saw you eddit it lol, but i get no change to the files contents?

Comment: This is a different question. The text had been changed. Now you need to save the text to a file.